# RIP William Morgan Sheppard: Star Trek, Babylon 5, Doctor Who, Max Headroom, many more

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Genre actor W. Morgan Sheppard, veteran of several franchises, [died yesterday](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/william-morgan-sheppard-death-cause-age-star-trek-doctor-who-mad-men-tribute-a8715406.html). Just some of his better known genre roles:

[image: Ira Graves]
Ira Graves (Data's grandpa), TNG: "The Schizoid Man"

[image: Commandant Rura Penthe]
The Klingon Commandant of Rura Penthe, Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country

[image: Rogue Soul Hunter]
The Rogue Soul Hunter in Babylon 5: Soul Hunter

[image: Blank Reg]
Blank Reg in Max Headroom

He was instantly recognizable with or without the latex, and he will be missed.

Comment: "I can safely say that to know him was to love him. And to love him was to know him. Those who knew him, loved him, while those who did not know him, loved him from afar."

Comment: He was also in *Doctor Who* (S6E1 "The Impossible Astronaut") together with his son, making him one of the few actors to have appeared in both ST and DW.

Comment: He is also the father of Mark Sheppard of Battlestar Galactica (Romo Lampkin), Supernatural (Crowley) and Firefly fame.